# Problem to run While Loop JavaScript in VS code

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Fibonacci sequence using a loop

```js
let nr1 = 0;
let nr2 = 1;
let temp;
fibonacciArray = [];
while (fibonacciArray.length < 25) {
  fibonacciArray.push(nr1);
  temp = nr1 + nr2;
  nr1 = nr2;
  nr2 = temp;
}
console.log(fibonacciArray);
```

> ReferenceError: fibonacciArray is not defined

I try this code it gives error message I try to declare variable fibonacciArray by 'let' but it didn't work.

Comment: I made your code runnable, I am not seeing the error

Comment: Works here - with out without let

Comment: Are you running the code in strict mode?

Comment: @Barmar I bet this is the problem.

Comment: @mplungjan Why did you add `let` in your edit? That may be the problem if the code is in strict mode.

Comment: "*try to declare variable fibonacciArray by 'let' but it didn't work.*" can you clarify? What is the code *with* `let` you tried and what is the problem you had? Please [edit] to provide a [mcve]